# Why Are some of my MVC2 View pages are unavailabe when I deploy to test environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment

I am deploying to a test environment to test what I have so far with my code in a real world environment (You know not on my local machine)... When I deploy however, I get this error...

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /mycustompage.htm

Now quick background on my application and how it should be running.  This is an intranet application so it is windows authentication.  I believe the settings on the server allow for that I will have to talk to the guy running the server to ensure that however.  But could there be other reasons why I am getting this error?  I am really stumped so far.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you installed the MVC extensions on the test environment?

Comment: They Guy who runs the server says that he did.  To be specific, do you have to more then just the .net Version 4.0 installed in the environment for this to work?  What is the MVC extension exactly?

Comment: [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/13/server-installation-options-for-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) is a link regarding MVC2 installation on the server.

Comment: @DmainEvent please paste the error stack trace